# Proving that $0=3\cdot x-4\cdot x^3$ holds for $x=\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have the following equation: $0=3\cdot x-4\cdot x^3$. Let $x=\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$. Now I should proof that this equation holds with the given $x$. Therefore I should use the following equations:

- $\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$
- $\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)$

I am not exactly sure how these formulas are supposed to help me. I got a value for $\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$ from this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626807/find-and-proof-the-exact-values-to-the-equations-sin-pi-3-cos-pi-3-sin) but I think that this will not help me either, because I am not supposed to just calculate the value of $\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$. I tried to somehow use the given formulas with $\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{3}))$ and $\sin((\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{3})+\frac{\pi}{3})$ because this is equal to $0$, but this ended in just a huge chain of equations from which I couldn't form a proof. I also looked at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316434/use-a-matrix-or-equations-to-find-the-value-of-sin-pi-3), but it didn't help me either, because the answer is using complex numbers but we should only stay in $\mathbb{R}$ . After I've proofed that the equation holds for $\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$ I should derive with three possible values for $\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$. I think that I can do this part on my own, but I  don't know how to do this proof.

I have problems to find the starting idea, especially because I have to use the given equations and I don't know how they could be used in the proof.

---

### My try with $\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{3}))$

I tried to somehow utilise the given formulas, for that I did the following.

\begin{align*}
&&0&=3\cdot\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})-4\cdot\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})^3\\
&\Leftrightarrow&\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{3}))&=3\cdot\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})+4\cdot\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})^3\\
&\Leftrightarrow&\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{3})+\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{3})&=3\cdot\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})-4\cdot\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})^3\\
&\Leftrightarrow&\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})\cdot(\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})-\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}))+\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})\cdot(\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})+\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}))&=3\cdot\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})-4\cdot\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})^3\\
\end{align*}

I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Please edit your post to show your attempt to calculate $\sin((\theta+\theta)+\theta)$ or $\sin((\theta+\theta)+\theta).$ This was the right idea, and won't be such "a huge chain of equations".

Comment: You know that $\cos(\pi/3) = 1/2$, so $x^2 = 1 - \cos^2(\pi/3) = 3/4$. Thus $4x^3 = 4x^2x = 3x$. Thus $3x-4x^3 = 0$.

Comment: @Stef The OP said they don't want to calculate the value of $\sin\frac\pi3$ (or equivalently, of $\cos\frac\pi3$).

Comment: As a first step, can you derive $\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta \cos \theta$ and $\cos(2\theta) = 1-2\sin^2\theta$, using your given identities?

Comment: @AnneBauval I edited my question according to your comment.

Comment: Then convert all $\cos\frac\pi3$ to $\sin\frac\pi3$, using $$\cos^2\frac\pi3 + \sin^2\frac\pi3 = 1$$.

Answer (score -1):

Use the identity $$\sin(3\theta)=3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta$$ Now the expression be $$3x-4x^3$$ Put $x=\sin\theta$ then observe that the expression will become $$3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta$$  which is actually equal to $$\sin(3\theta)$$ Now it is given that $$3x-4x^3=0$$ which means that $$\sin(3\theta)=0$$ Now we know that $\sin\pi=0$ $$\implies \sin\pi=\sin(3\theta)$$ $$\implies 3\theta=\pi$$ or $$\boxed{\color{red}\theta\color{red}=\frac{\color{red}\pi}{\color{red}3}}$$

Comment: I am not really understanding your approach here. You are showing that $\Theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$ but this is already given and I have to proof that $0=3\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})-4\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})^3$. So this is not shown, because this is not shown I can't use it as the identity $sin(3\Theta)=3\sin(\Theta)-4\sin(\Theta)^3$ or what am I understanding wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this?

$0=4x^3-3x=x(4x^2-3)=x(2x-\sqrt{3})(2x+\sqrt{3})$

So $x\in \{\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 0 \}$

$\sin(\pi /3)=\sqrt{3}/2$